# forcing Validation; WPF, DataGrid, ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a WPF DataGrid. I read a csv file and build an ObservableCollection of objects. 
I set the DataGrid.ItemsSource to the Collection. I would like to then force a RowValidation on every row in the DataGrid.  If I, playing user, edit a cell, the RowValidation fires, all is well.  But the Validation does not fire on the initial load.  Is there some way I can call ??ValidateRow?? on a row?  on every row?
(C#, WPF, VS2008, etc)

Comment: You can try `row.BindingGroup.ValidateWithoutUpdate()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/42476772/2122718

Answer (score 2):

For your bindings, set the UpdateSourceTrigger to property changed, and then put your validation rules inside that. The default update source trigger is Lost Focus.

```
  <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
```

Also, for another good solution, have a look here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx

Paul builds a custom error provider, like

> You can call the Validate() method on
>   the ErrorProvider to force validation,
>   and check if the controls are valid

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup a RowValidationRule and set the ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" if you want it to validate after initial loading of the ObservableCollection

```
        <DataGrid Name="dgCsvObjects"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CsvObjects}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                <Validation:MyObjectValidationRule ValidationStep="ConvertedProposedValue" />
            </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property1" Binding="{Binding Path=Property1}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property2" Binding="{Binding Path=Property2}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property3" Binding="{Binding Path=Property3}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property4" Binding="{Binding Path=Property4}"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```