# Validate row when underlying data changes

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Imagine a DataGrid with its `ItemsSource` set to an `ObservableCollection`. This collection provides a view model for each row in the `DataGrid`. The view model in turn provides the data that is displayed in one row and a command that may change this data. Additionally, I added a rule to the  `RowValidationRules` property of `DataGrid`. This validation rule works fine in case I enter invalid data.

However, if I change the invalid data to valid data via the command the view model provides, the row validation rule only gets triggered again if the current row in `DataGrid` loses focus. Hence, the displayed data may be actually valid, but the `DataGrid` still displays a red exclamation mark showing it has invalid data. This remains the case until the current row loses focus or I enter valid data again.

How do I force a second validation of the current row? I already set `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"` but this didn't solve the problem. I also have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface but this also didn't fix the problem.

**Solution**

As user [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484903/1549233) pointed out, `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is the approach to go. I removed the row validation rule and exposed a property named `HasErros` in my view model that proxies the `HasErrors` property of my model that in turn implements `INotifyDataErrorInfo`. Next I added a custom `RowValidationErrorTemplate`

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Width="12" Height="12" Fill="Red"/>
            <Label Content="!" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="White" FontSize="11"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
```

and created the following custom style for `DataGridRowHeader`

```
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridRowHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        <Control SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                 Template="{Binding ValidationErrorTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}"
                                 Visibility="{Binding Path=HasErrors, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <!-- ... -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note the binding of `Visibility`. The `HasErrors` property is the proxy property I mentioned above.

And finally, use that style in the `DataGrid` as follows

```
<DataGrid RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridRowHeaderStyle}"
...
```

An implementation of `BoolToVisibilityConverter` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28517042/1549233).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a `ValidationRule` to the `RowValidationRules` property of the `DataGrid` you could implement the [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) interface in the view model class and raise its `ErrorChanged` event whenever you want to refresh the status of a row/item.

This is the MVVM way of implementing data validation. Using a `ValidationRule` is not.

**WPF 4.5: Validating Data in Using the INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface:** https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can handle `CellEditEnding`, find the Rows and call `UpdateSources` of the `BindingGroup`:

```
    private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        foreach (var r in dg.Items)
        {
            DataGridRow row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(r) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null)
                row.BindingGroup.UpdateSources();
        }
    }
```

Also, note to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` for your bindings too.

**Edit**

Note that you can also use `EventTrigger`:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1"   ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" DataContext="{Binding}"> 
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PCommand}" 
                                   CommandParameter="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</DataGrid>
```

in which `PCommand` is in the ViewModel and:

```
    private void DoPCommand(object parameter)
    {
        DataGrid dg = parameter as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null)
            foreach (var r in dg.Items)
            {
                DataGridRow row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(r) as DataGridRow;
                if (row != null)
                    row.BindingGroup.UpdateSources();
            }
    }
```

Comment: In my case also working `row.BindingGroup.ValidateWithoutUpdate();`